# Conceal the INSERT order in MySQL database table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-insert

By definition, the rows in a MySQL table have no reliable "natural" order, unless I add an incrementing ID, timestamp, or such. However, I can often reconstruct the order in which rows have been added (INSERT) when running a SELECT without ORDER.

For privacy reasons, I am trying to get rid of this "internal" order. If I had en Excel sheet, I would insert the new row before another, randomly chosen row. But there's no `INSERT AFTER` in MySQL...

Any ideas?

**Background**

I need to conceal that two rows (inserted in the same table "at the same time", even within a transaction) belong together. And one (an evil employee, someone hacking the server) should not be able to reconstruct the relation of these two entries.

**Solutions already considered**

- Re-Creating a copy of the database, using `INSERT SELECT` -> won't work, because the table is quite large, there are many inserts, and locking the table for re-writing would be an issue.
- Delete and re-insert another row when a couple is added -> in a large table, many rows would stay in the original order, chance lacks reliability :(

Comment: "By definition, the rows in a MySQL table have no reliable "natural" order, unless I add an incrementing ID, timestamp, or such" Indeed and when you use ORDER BY when you SELECT from that table to maintain that order.

Comment: Your best option might be a stored procedure..But hard to say without example tables, example data and expected output.

Comment: @RaymondNijland His "expected output" is the negation of an expectation. He wants the result of a query without `ORDER BY` to be unrelated to the order that the rows were inerted.

Comment: @RaymondNijland He wants to prevent users from inferring the insertion order.

Comment: Why are you allowing untrusted users to run custom queries directly against the DB? If you force them to go through your API, you should be able to use `ORDER BY` clauses to prevent them from detecting the stored order.

Comment: I won't allow untrusted users SQL access deliberately - but you can never be 100% sure that nobody will bypass my allowance... Finally, security is always a balance between costs and the desired security level. If there was a way to store the data without an order, that's an additional level of security.

Comment: Using a natural key (like email address) might be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default storage engine, InnoDB, always organizes a table by its primary key. If you query without `ORDER BY`, MySQL returns rows in the index order it uses to access the table (either primary key order or the order of whatever secondary index is used).

This might be a good opportunity to use a UUID as the primary key.

A UUID appears to be a random unique number, although it does have some structure. Inferring which rows are near each other chronologically would require [reading some documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) (which means virtually all potential evil employees won't know anything about it).

Answer (score 1):

As Bill Karwin already indicated (and I am repeating here) InnoDB tables are always organized "in order" by the cluster key. And for a cluster key, InnoDB uses the PRIMARY KEY. If no PRIMARY KEY, then the first non-null UNIQUE KEY. Otherwise, a synthetic key.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

To get rows inserted in a more "random" order, we would need a cluster key that doesn't reveal insert order.

But changing the cluster key would require a rebuild of the table rebuild, which seems to have already been ruled out.

Bill Karwin suggested using a UUID as the cluster key.

Another alternative would be to add a synthetic column as the leading column in the cluster key, the value of the synthetic column could be populated by a BEFORE INSERT trigger. The trigger could use an algorithm to generate a pseudo-random value, using a hash computed from other column values and/or the return from RAND() function.

We would also need to ensure that there aren't any other indexes by which the insert order could be determined.

But all of these options would require a rebuild of the table.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, especially the hint on the synthetic key. Rebuilding the table is not an issue per se, I just ruled out to do this regularly (e.g., once per hour) - which also would probably be a quite stupid idea...